# .NET Maui with Amplify CLI and AppSync

Tags: windows, aws-amplify, maui, aws-appsync

I'm looking for a way to make my app multi-platform, and I'm looking into Microsoft .NET Maui.
Is there a way to use AWS Amplify and AppSync with it?

AWS Amplify says it works with iOS, Android, and web. I see java and javascript supported, but no C#.

Is there a way to use .NET Maui with AWS Amplify?

Comment: Try out a spike solution to quickly test crud. You should be able to interact with the AppSync backend since it'll break down to GQL over HTTP. Not sure how easily you could get subscriptions working. A quick search revealed some 'nuget' package.

Comment: Yup, you can totally use AppSync with .NET MAUI. You'll want to use the AWSSDK.AppSync NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.AppSync